# error while trying to declare a struct that was defined with typedef in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am trying to declare a struct,
in myHeader.h I have defined  the following struct type

```
typedef Books
{
    int field1;
    int field2;
}book;
```

When I am trying to declare a struct of type Books like this.

```
book b1; //in src.c that includes myHeader.h`
```

I am geting an error that says:

> 'book' : illegal use of this type as an expression.

Comment: you just need to add a `struct` between the `typedef` and `Books` :)

Comment: The corrected code should work; you are likely missing a semicolon or closing brace or have another "trivial" error in your source.

Comment: ___Please do not change a question once it is answered. Thanks.___ You must check for typos before posting the question.

Answer (score 2):

During definition, using `typedef` does not allow you to *leave out* the `struct` keyword . You can use the new type *without* the `struct` keyword.

Your

```
typedef Books
{
```

should be

```
 typedef struct Books
 {
```

and later, you can use

```
 book b1;
```

as you like.

Comment: it is as you mentioned with the struct keyword between typedef and struct name, but the error still appears, my bad I missed the struct keyword while posting the question, I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @MihaiG in that case, You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: It is exactly as I have written in the question post, nothing is different